# opcua python library call_method how to use

Tags: python, opc-ua

i want to achieve the methods to call like this message([image: want to acieve]),but my code acieve this message[image: had achieved].I want to know how to achieve my goal?

This is my code:

```
from opcua import Client,ua

server_url = "opc.tcp://localhost:4840"

client = Client(server_url)
client.connect()

try:
    method_0 = client.get_node("ns=1;s=getCurrentClock")
    parent_obj_0 = "ns=1;s=ClockProvider"
    obj_0 = client.get_node(parent_obj_0)
    out_0 = obj_0.call_method(method_0)
    print(out_0)


    method_1 = client.get_node("ns=1;s=getCurrentAbsTime")
    parent_obj_1 = "ns=1;s=AbsTimeProvider"
    obj_1 = client.get_node(parent_obj_1)
    out_1 = obj_1.call_method(method_1)
    print(out_1)

    method_2 = client.get_node("ns=1;s=getError")
    parent_obj_2 = "ns=1;s=Status"
    obj_2 = client.get_node(parent_obj_2)
    out_2 = obj_2.call_method(method_2)
    print(out_2)

    method_3 = client.get_node("ns=1;s=getTracking")
    parent_obj_3 = "ns=1;s=Status"
    obj_3 = client.get_node(parent_obj_3)
    out_3 = obj_3.call_method(method_3)
    print(out_3)

finally:
    client.disconnect()
```

I've tried to implement it with arrays, but method calls are still separate messages, not grouped together in the same message.Someone can help?thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you say it in detail, or do you have the code for example, thank you again@Schroeder

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have achieved what I wanted, but I found that the statuscode of every method in wireshark shows BadNodeIdUnknown. And when I use UaExpert, it says good, I don't think there is a problem with the server, thank you again for your help.@Schroeder

Comment: Check the wireshark CallMethodRequest paramter values and match these in your code.

Comment: Thanks, there is still a value I do not know how to modify my code to match. Methods are called in Uaexpert, and the InputArguments of each method showed in wireshark is "arraySize: -1", I understand that this method has only output parameters and no input parameters, but my code shows in wireshark is "arraySize: 0", whether I delete the line of code that fills in the input parameters or assign an empty array, I can't change it. And this causes me to get a different value for the output argument from uaexpert.How should I modify the code? thank you.@Schroeder

Comment: arraySize:0 is the same as arraySize:-1

Comment: I still has a question.The Dewesoft server has a method called getCurrentAbstime. I make my own python code calls, or the output parameter obtained by calling the method with uaexpert is -1, but I use Dewesoft's client to call this method, and it turns out to be a string of numbers 210116000, my understanding is that this string of numbers is a mask for real time, why can't I get that kind of output, how should I get it?thank you@Schroeder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256113/discussion-between-baixianjie-and-schroeder).

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. You could use the uaclient object of the client class and call [call](https://python-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/opcua/client/ua_client.html#UaClient.call). The argument for this call are the values you see in wireshark.

Added a example:

```
methodstocall = []
# tuples of obj and method
nodes = [("ns=1;s=getCurrentClock", "ns=1;s=ClockProvider"), ...]
for objectid, methodid in nodes:
    request = ua.CallMethodRequest()
    request.ObjectId = ua.NodeId(objectid)
    request.MethodId = ua.NodeId(methodid)
    request.InputArguments = [] # add arguments here if needed
    methodstocall.append(request)
results = client.uaclient.call(methodstocall)
```